# What does "basic upstanding citizen types" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Batman (2022), Batman asks Selina about club:

> Batman: Is that where you work?
>
> Selina: No, I just work the bar upstairs. But I see 'em come in.
>
> Batman: Who?
>
> Selina: A lot of guys that shouldn't be there, I can tell you that.
> Your **basic upstanding citizen types**.

What does "basic upstanding citizen types" mean?

Comment: I did answer your last question of "what does this mean" but to be honest, that isn't what the site is meant for. The advice I gave along with my last answer was to break the sentence down. If you break it down, you'll be able to look these words up in a dictionary and get the meaning. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: *X is **your basic Y*** is a colloquial idiomatic form meaning *X is **just an ordinary X, with no special additional features***. The more "formal" version replaces determiner ***your*** with an indefinite article (for *singular* contexts; in *plural* contexts as per the example here, the "formal" version simply discards ***your***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably sarcasm, as saying that they should not be there and yet saying they are "upstanding citizens" - law abiding citizens/behaving in a good and moral way

So Selina is probably being sarcastic to emphasise how they are not law abiding (not following the law)